# How do I recover from TransactionFailureException?

Tags: neo4j

Something went wrong with the application in the middle of a transaction (the thread was killed, which resulted in a ThreadDeath etc.), so the transaction failed, but no new transaction could be started after:

```
org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException: 
Kernel has encountered some problem, please perform neccesary action (tx recovery/restart)
```

What are the actions I should undertake to deal with this issue?

Update: I forgot to mention that I have encountered this type of error before and managed to (at least temporarily) fix it by deleting transaction log files. But now, apparently, there aren't any `*nioneo*` (IIRC) files in the neo4j data directory at all! Did the location or names of log files change? Or am I missing something? There are `neostore.transaction.db.x` files, which, upon grepping seem to contain chunks of my data. I did start the fresh instance of the application (fortunately that was a test), so I can't check it now, but if I deleted them, would I be able to restart an app from the previous state?

Comment: anything interesting in `messages.log`?

Comment: Nope. I forgot to mention another weird thing, check out my update to the question in a couple of minutes, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the improvements in Neo4j 2.2 was the unification of transaction logs, those are now in `neostore.transaction.db.x`.

In case the db does not start any more you can try to remove them (but be sure to keep a backup copy) and restart the database. However try a restart with these files in place beforehand. If the presence of transaction logs causes the database not to start up I would consider this being a bug.

Comment: I managed to write a test that reproduces this exception. Yes, restarting the database seems to fix the problem, but I'm thinking on filing a bug report about this behavior.